# Update or insert using SSIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ssis, azure-synapse

I have a situation where i need to update or insert my destination table using below condition.If  a field(TYPE) in my destination table has value 'z' then i need to update the destination using source table.Else i need to insert the entry from source with TYPE = 'z' in the destination.I can only use ssis to do this task(strictly no store procedure  ).Please let me know how can i do it ?

> Error at Data flow task [OLEDB command [189]]: ssis error code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An oledb error has occured. Error code 0x80004005
>   .An oledb record is available. Source Microsoft SQL server native
>   cliemt 11.0 Hresult =0x80004005 Description :Store procedure
>   sp_describe_undeclared_parameters doesn't exist or is not supported

Code used in update:

```
UPDATE Table SET Column=? WHERE TYPE = 'Z'
```

Im also trying to use script component to update as im new to c# could anyone please guide me how we can do it in c#script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? What does your package look like now? How many records do you expect to do this for? You basically need to use a conditional split to split your update and insert rows. Your insert rows go to a standard destination. Your update rows go to an execute SQL target. I will find one of the many answers on this site and link to it

Comment: I can't find a good example. You need to open Visual Studio, create a package, create a data flow. Inside the dataflow, define a source. Feed that source through a conditional split. In that split you put your `TYPE='Z'` logic. This splits the data into two outputs. One of the data outputs goes into a standard data flow destination (which inserts). The other goes into a `SSIS OLE DB Command`, which is an update statement that uses parameters. Please do this, and when you run into an issue, post a picture of your package and clearly explain the issue. Right now you don't really have a question

Comment: Lookup transformation is what you're looking for. The below example in the article should help you:
http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/46-SSIS-Upsert-With-Lookup-Transform.html

Comment: Just reread your question. Yes you'd need to use a lookup transformation rather than a conditional split. Not that it matters becauxe this looks to be abandoned now

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply guys , i tried using merge statement in the execute sql task but that doesn't work as my source is in one database and destination is on another database with in the same server. Also we dont have TYPE field in the source , we only have it in the destination table  ,so every time we update it i need to check it with the destination and then load from source table. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Why don’t you try what I mentioned in my comment but use a lookup instead of a conditional spli

Comment: Yeah i tried using lookup, for no match output im inserting data in oledb destination and for no match output im updating using oledb command but getting an error in coulmn mapping which says stored procedure sp_describe_undeclared_parameters doesnt exist or is not supported. I think it doesnt support for azure datawarhouse . I attached a error pic above please do have a look at it thanks @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Can you paste the error as text in your question? Because the next thing I do is highlight the error, right click and google search. I've only had success with ADO.Net connections to SQL Azure. I will do some more investigation. Can you also add the SQL Azure tag to your question?

Comment: I tested using the `OLE DB Command` against Azure and it worked OK for me. On the component properties in the _SqlCommand_ property you should have something like `UPDATE Table SET Column=? WHERE AnotherColumn = ?` then in the _column mappings_ tab you need to map your columns to the `?` parameters placeholders. See here for a complicated example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368952/ssis-updating-a-table-with-a-ole-db-command

Comment: Hi i have posted exact error below. Please have a look at it.Error at Data flow task [OLEDB command [189]]: ssis error code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An oledb error has occured. Error code 0x80004005 .An oledb record is available.  Source Microsoft  SQL server native cliemt 11.0 Hresult =0x80004005 Description :Store procedure sp_describe_undeclared_parameters doesn't exist or is not supported.

Comment: So i used this to update UPDATE Table SET Column=? WHERE TYPE = 'Z'

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, although I am using Visual Studio 2017 (which you should probably use also). That `UPDATE` statement is incorrect.It's going to update the same bunch of rows over and over. You need a `WHERE` clause. I have edited your question and added the information that you posted in comments.

Comment: I used the update statement as you said but still getting the same error. Can i use script component ? if yes do you know how to write a C# code? @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Yes you can use script component but you shouldn't have to. Here's an example but there are _many_ other examples. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-data-flow-script-component-types/creating-a-destination-with-the-script-component?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I just realised you are using SQL Data Warehouse. It is very important to describe your environment. I incorrectly tagged SQL Azure. Now I'll change it. In future please tag your question with the correct information. Anyway it looks like there is no SSIS update capability. But for SQL datawarehouse you shouldn't be doing this anyway

Comment: Given that a stored procedure is the best tool for this job, why are you excluding that option.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be possible to use a [CTAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-as-select-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016), [RENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/rename-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016) then drop the initial table? The Insert operation will be serial where the CTAS will take advantage of the platform and run in parallel. The RENAME(s) and drop will be fast meta operations. DDL like RENAME cannot be in a transaction.

Comment: You can do better than renaming tables. CTAS as you've suggested, Allan, then use this recent variant: ALTER TABLE <t2> SWITCH TO <t1> WITH (TRUNCATE_TARGET=ON). Keeps your table and metadata in place.

Comment: My source is in different database and my destination is in different database. If create CTASfrom source table im unable to use it in the destination database to update . Showing me an error as follows:
Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Reference to database and/or server name in 'Source_Table' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.