# How to update a SQL table from an SSIS Power Query Source resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, powerquery

in an SSIS package I have a "Power Query" Source step that results to 3 columns, Region, Facility and Weekly_Amount. I am interested in updating a SQL table with the Power Query's Weekly_Amount column, where Region and Facility relate to SQL table record. Example:

```
Update {Some table}
set {SQL Table}.Weekly_Amount = {PowerQuery}.Weekly_Amount 
where {SQL Table}.Region = {PowerQuery}.Region
and {SQL Table}.Facility = {PowerQuery}.Facility
```

What SSIS step do I need to use in order to accomplish the above? I can always include a T-Sql Update statement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Oledb Command

You can use an OLEDB Command transformation within the Data Flow Task to do that:

```
Update {SQL Table}
set {SQL Table}.Weekly_Amount = ?
where {SQL Table}.Region = ?
and {SQL Table}.Facility = ?
```

And map the columns to the parameters in the OLEDB Command configuration form.

**References and helpful articles**

- [Update Data Using OLEDB Command Transformation in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/update-data-using-oledb-command-transformation-in-ssis/)
- [SSIS - Updating a table with a OLE DB Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368952/ssis-updating-a-table-with-a-ole-db-command)

---

### Staging Table

Using OLEDB command is not recommended from performance perspective since it will execute an update statement for each row in the data pipeline.

You can import data into a staging table and use an Execute SQL Task to update data using a similar query:

```
Update {SQL Table}
set {SQL Table}.Weekly_Amount = {Staging Table}.Weekly_Amount
FROM {SQL Table} INNER JOIN {Staging Table} 
    ON {SQL Table}.Region = {Staging Table}.Region 
    AND {SQL Table}.Facility = {Staging Table}.Facility
```

Comment: Hi Hadi, thank you very much. It did the job!!! Especially the 1st link was very helpful.